# How should I use ccache if the compiler absolute path is hard-coded in the makefile?

Tags: c, unix, gnu-make, ccache

It's not an option for me to modify the complicated nest of makefiles that builds our code, and in various places they construct absolute paths to very specific compilers, e.g. `/home/arm2gcc/gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2018-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc`

That makes it hard to use ccache either as a prefix or by putting it first in the path.

So I wonder about moving the compiler installations on my personal machine to e.g. `/home/arm2gcc-real` and putting fake scripts in `/home/arm2gcc` that redirect to the real compilers.

Can anyone suggest how to do this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Submit a ticket to clean up the build system.

Comment: I've had a look, it looks like quite a big job! And in fact having a working ccache would be a step on the road to convincing people that it would help to do the build right.

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:** I've only limited experience with Ccache and CMake.*

Can you try adding this in the root CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_program(CCACHE ccache)
if(CCACHE)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE ${CCACHE})
endif()
```

If that does not work, I think we may need some more info on how the compilers are setup exactly in your CMakeLists.txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
mv .../bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc .../bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.real
```

Then, create a script to replace `.../bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ccache ${0}.real "$@"
```